# Upper and lower border around a UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I have a `UIImage` inside a `UITableViewCell`. 
What is the best way to have upper and lower borders around the `UIImage`?

```
[cell.backgroundImageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[cell.backgroundImageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];    
cell.backgroundImageView.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.backgroundImageView.layer.frame.size.width + 10, cell.backgroundImageView.layer.frame.size.height);
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: add two `CGLayers`s one on top and another to bottom

Comment: How do I place it on top and bottom ? Constraints?

Comment: No, layers are kind of old-school things, you need to set their frames manually in code:)

Answer (score 0):

The border properties manage a border around the whole layer, not a partial one.

I'd go with a couple of UIViews (with their background color set as needed), pinned to the UIImageView using autolayout and pinned within the cell frame. In that way you don't risk drawing the borders outside the bounds of the cell, or having your other cell content mis-aligned to the image, since the image appears to be a certain size but it actually larger because you have been playing with the layers.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not a consideration you can add a UIView with 1px height above and below the image and set its background color.